# Non-Modal Notification Box from batch script

Tags: batch-file, notifications, alerts

I would like to have a non-modal alert box called form a batch file.  Currently I am using vbscript to create a modal alert box:

```
>usermessage.vbs ECHO WScript.Echo^( "Generating report - this may take a moment." ^)
WSCRIPT.EXE usermessage.vbs
```

But I would like to proceed with the script (generating the report) without waiting for user interaction.  How can I accomplish this?  I don't care if it's vbscript or not - I just want it to work from my batch script (in Windows XP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer that has no new requirements over your current trick is to use the `start` command to detach the script from the batch file execution.

That might look something like:

```
>usermessage.vbs ECHO WScript.Echo^( "Generating report - this may take a moment." ^)
start WSCRIPT.EXE usermessage.vbs
echo This text is a proxy for the hard work of writing the report
```

where the only difference is using `start` to run `wscript`. This does suffer from the defect that it leaves a temporary file laying around in the current directory, and that the box does need to be eventually manually dismissed.

Both issues are easy to handle:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set msg="%TMP%\tempmsg.vbs"
ECHO WScript.Echo^( "Generating report - this may take a moment." ^) >%msg% 
start WSCRIPT.EXE /I /T:15 %msg%
echo This text is a proxy for the hard work of writing the report
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >NULL
del %msg% >NUL 2>&1
```

Here, I move the temporary script over to the `%TMP%` folder, and remember to delete it when we're done with it. I used an `echo` and a `ping` command to waste some time to demonstrate a long process running. And, I used the `/I` and `/T` options to `wscript` to make certain that the script is run "interactively" and to set a maximum time to allow the script to run.

The `@echo off` and `setlocal` make it look cleaner when running at a command prompt and prevent it from leaving the name `%msg% in the prompt's environment.

**Edit:** Johannes Rössel's criticism of `setlocal` in the comments is incorrect. If this is invoked at a command prompt, without the `setlocal` the variable msg will be visible to the prompt and to other batch files and programs launched from that prompt. It is good practice to use `setlocal` to isolate local variables in a batch file if one is actually writing anything more than a throw-away script.

This can be easily demonstrated:

```
C:> type seta.bat 
@set A=SomeValue

C:> set A
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
APPDATA=C:\Documents and Settings\Ross\Application Data

C:> seta.bat

C:> set A
A=SomeValue
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
APPDATA=C:\Documents and Settings\Ross\Application Data

C:>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you are assuming that cmd.exe is too much like a *nix shell. Each batch file invoked at a command prompt is interpreted by that very copy of cmd.exe and can indeed change the environment for other commands. That is why setlocal was added. You are correct if a batch file is invoked from explorer, however. This has been true since DOS 1.0 and COMMAND.COM, and remains true at least in XP.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same issue, I had a VBScript that needed to pop up a message box but not stop and continue on. And I wanted to close after a certain amount of time. This worked for me. Essentially one vbscript creates another vbscript file and then uses shellexecute to execute that message box file with a timeout of say 15 seconds.

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
tmpPath = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%TMP%" )
set wshShell = Nothing

msgFile = tmpPath & "\tempmsg.vbs"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = fs.CreateTextFile(msgFile,True)
objFile.Write "MsgBox " & chr(34) & "It worked!" & chr(34) & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
Set fs = Nothing

dim objShell
set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objShell.ShellExecute "cscript.exe", "/I /T:15 " & (char34) & msgFile & chr(34), "", "open", 0
set objShell = Nothing
```